# How to publish a .net framework windows service

Tags: powershell, .net-core, azure-devops, app-config

I have a windows service I build with .net core and I can publish it with a publish profile and since Im using appsettings I can target the environment as well.  Trying to figure out a solution for another project but its using .net framework and do not want to use installutil.  So far I can just 
- stop the service 
- copy over the files 
- restart the service

However, with a .net framework service, the settings are in app.config and the settings will be different obviously between a test server and production.

So now I am looking at doing this with powershell, and hopefully add this to a build pipeline to have it automated. The steps would be the same that the powershell script would do
- stop the service on the target server
- copy over the files from the /bin folder
- restart the service on the target server
except after copying over the files, I would need to modify the app.config, and all of the above Im sure I can accomplish with powershell.

My question is, can this be done via a build pipeline that runs on a on-prem build agent?

Comment: Is it what you want to add [PowerShell on target machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) task to build pipeline?

Comment: Probably, except the target is the same machien that the build agent is running on.  Thanks for the suggestion, Im looking at that. There are on-prem build agents on each machine that a build targets.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can this be done via a build pipeline that runs on a on-prem build
>   agent

For this issue , according to your situation, as mentioned by penaunt in the comment, you can try adding PowerShell on target machines task to the build pipeline.

You can use this task to execute PowerShell scripts on remote machines. This task uses Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to access on-premises physical computers or virtual computers that are domain-joined or workgroup-joined. For PowerShell scripts, the computers must have PowerShell 2.0 or higher installed.

```
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  displayName: 'Run PowerShell on Target Machines'
  inputs:
    Machines: '...'
    #userName: # Optional
    #userPassword: # Optional
    #scriptType: 'Inline'
    #inlineScript: '# Write your powershell commands here'
    #scriptArguments: # Optional
```

Comment: Its probably even easier, since the target is the same machine where the build agent is located and powershell is already installed there.